# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "А позже(,) в реальном мире(,) люди начали ценить его идеи"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, недопустимая-метка, уточнения

Учительница пометила как пунктуационную ошибку запятые в предложении: "А позже, в реальном мире, люди начали ценить его идеи". Я думаю, что она не права, так как "в реальном мире" можно обособить как уточнение. Нужны ли запятые здесь и почему?
P.s. предложение составляла не я, просто интересно узнать ответ)

Comment: Нужен контект, а то семантика неясна. Там два мира, реальный и еще какой-то?

Comment: смысл в том, что сначала в сочинении шла речь о прошлом, что идеи человека люди не ценили, а в реальном мире начали ценить. поэтому думаю, что "в реальном мире" может считаться уточнением

Comment: Я думала, фантастика какая) Тогда здесь проблема с лексикой, надо заменить слово. Например, в мире нашей реальности. И тогда это будет обособленное по времени уточнение:  А позже, в мире нашей реальности,  люди начали ценить его идеи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя обособить как уточнение к слову, отвечающему на вопрос "когда?", словосочетание, отвечающее на вопрос "где?".

Запятые не нужны.

Comment: интересно, спасибо за ответ 

Comment: Если помог, кликните по треугольничку! )))